# Center-align one element and right align second element- Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have attached a rough idea of what I am trying to achieve, the dotted line represents the center of the container.
I am trying to center align one div element, then right align a second div within the same row, while both elements are centered horizontally.
[image]

Comment: Could you include what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex items-center justify-center border border-dashed">
  <div class="flex-1"></div>
  <div class="w-32 h-32 bg-red-500"></div>
  <div class="flex-1">
    <div class="w-20 h-20 bg-green-500 ml-auto"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With grid:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-[minmax(0,1fr),auto,minmax(0,1fr)] items-center border border-dashed">
  <div></div>
  <div class="w-32 h-32 bg-red-500"></div>
  <div class="w-20 h-20 bg-green-500 ml-auto"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me the trick was `justify-between`. Makes it so the way the flexbox grows, the free space is distributed in between the elements.

Here's a snippet:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col content-center justify-center mt-16 mx-auto max-w-xl">
    <!-- Top level info -->
    <div class="flex justify-between w-full">
        <h3 class="h3">Sign In</h3>
        <p class="p">Dashboard / Sign In</p>
    </div>
</div>
```